# Python output contains extra variables

Tags: python

I have run into an error where a block of code in python 3.7 has caused multiple outputs where one is expected. The code is as follows:

```
def main():
    length=0;height=0;width=0;volume=0
    length,height,width=getinput(length,height,width)
    volume=processing(length,height,width,volume)
    output(volume)
def getinput(length,height,width):
    length, height, width = input("Enter length, height, and width:").split(',')
    length = int(length)
    height = int(height)
    width = int(width)
    return length,height,width
def processing(length,height,width,volume):
    volume = length * height * width
    return length,height,width,volume
def output(volume):
    print("the volume of the prism is:", volume)
main()
```

The output should be:

```
the volume of the prism is: 400
```

The output is:

```
the volume of the prism is: (20, 10, 2, 400)
```

Comment: `output` prints `volume`, which comes from `processing`, which returns `length,height,width,volume`. Four outputs are expected. If you are expecting one, `return volume` from `processing`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `def processing(length,height,width,volume)` function, the return statement  is `return length,height,width,volume` which basically means that you are returning a `tuple` and when you are catching it into a variable called volume, it becomes a tuple. See in the output you have `(20, 10, 2, 400)`. The braces shows that it is a `tuple`. You can also confirm that by printing `type(volume)`. If you want to get `400` as an answer, please do `output(volume[3])`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to do this:

```
>>> def processing(length,height,width,volume):
...     volume = length * height * width
...     return volume
...
>>> main()
Enter length, height, and width:20, 10, 2
the volume of the prism is: 400
```